# Is hand that used for Istinja impure?

Tags: taharah

If I urinating and at the tip of my penis The tip of my penis left a little urine, then I washed it by draining water from the top of my penis while rubbing the tip of my penis with my left fingers, i only cleaned it my penis like that just once,are my fingers unclean? And if after that i touch my clothes are my clothes become impure? Please help to answer this , because after i do that i touch many things with wet hands

Comment: The Muslim himself is pure at least for the living one there's consensus. But one can touch najis things and simply needs to wash the corresponding body parts.

Comment: @Medi1Saif sorry i don't understand what u mean